# pandas read_csv specify dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv-file that is 170 mb of size and has a 3-row-header.
On my machine that has 3 Gb of memory (1,3 Gb are used before starting), using

```
pd.read_csv(filepath, header = None, skiprows=[1,2,3])
```

I get

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py:1130: DtypeWarning: Columns (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

then some more error hints and finally

```
MemoryError
```

My data is as follows:
first column is a string (represents a date)
all other columns are numbers

The amount of columns is not known and must be treated dynamically for different csv-files.
How to specify the dtypes?

Comment: One strategy would be just to read the first row to get the number of columns and then enumerate the column headings and specify the dtypes and set this param e.g. `df = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None, skiprows=[1,2,3], nrows=1) cols = list(df.columns) # enumerate names and dtypes into a dict df = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None, skiprows=[1,2,3], dtype = dtype_dict)` this is pseudo code. You can also set `parse_dates = True` if you want datetime as a dtype

Comment: I will try it. Still wondering why there is a memory issue. 170 mb should fit X times into 2 Gb of free memory

Comment: Don't know but you can try to force the python garbage collector to recover any memory by `import gc` and then explicitly call `del temp_var` `gc.collect()`, again pseudo code.